# Transfer binary files between NodeJS apps

Tags: javascript, node.js

We need to transfer binary files (they can be > 50M ) between nodejs apps (can be on same machine or on different) . As I understand there are several options to do it:
1) By using Socket.IO
2) Over HTTP

What is preferable option and why ?
Your information will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Transfer between two Node.JS instances?

You can use a TCP connection. There are some modules that helps you with that.

I know this module:

- https://github.com/nodejitsu/nssocket